# Sample a single row, per column, within a subset of a data frame in R, while following conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, sample, missing-data

As an example of my data, I have GROUP 1 with three rows of data, and GROUP 2 with two rows of data, in a data frame:

```
GROUP   VARIABLE 1   VARIABLE 2   VARIABLE 3 
    1            2            6            5 
    1            4           NA            1 
    1           NA            3            8
    2            1           NA            2      
    2            9           NA           NA
```

I would like to sample a single variable, per column from GROUP 1, to make a new row representing GROUP 1.  I do not want to sample one single and complete row from GROUP 1, but rather the sampling needs to occur individually for each column.  I would like to do the same for GROUP 2.  Also, the sampling should not consider/include NA's, unless all rows for that group's variable have NA's (such as GROUP 2, VARIABLE 2, above).

For example, after sampling, I could have as a result:

```
GROUP   VARIABLE 1   VARIABLE 2   VARIABLE 3 
    1            4            6            1 
    2            9           NA            2
```

Only GROUP 2, VARIABLE 2, can result in `NA` here.  I actually have 39 groups, 50,000+ variables, and a substantial number of `NA`.  I would sincerely appreciate the code to make a new data frame of rows, each row having the sampling results per group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'GROUP', we loop through the columns (`lapply(.SD,`), `if` `all` of the elements are NA we return NA or else we get the `sample` of non-NA elements.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,lapply(.SD, function(x)
     if(all(is.na(x))) NA_integer_ else sample(na.omit(x),1)) , by = GROUP]
```

Comment: How do I replace x in this code?  Rather than sampling within each group, the code resulted in an integer for each group, for how many rows were not "NA."  I am guessing I have misinterpreted how to insert my data frame into the code.  This is what I wrote (with TABLE being the name of my data frame):  `setDT(TABLE)[,lapply(.SD, function(TABLE)
     if(all(is.na(TABLE))) NA_integer_ else sample(na.omit(TABLE),1)) , by = TABLE$GROUP]`

Comment: @user3545679 Based on the input data you showed, I am getting the expected output.  If `TABLE` is the name of the dataset, why you are using in `function(TABLE)`, it seems less wordy with `function(x)`

Comment: I think the problem may be that I am now actually working on a data frame of letters, rather than numbers.  As a result, for some columns, I get an integer of how many letters (not NA's) are present in the group.  Should I ask my question again, but for letters instead?  And, yes, I am now using x instead of TABLE.

Comment: @user3545679 If your columns are `character` then use `NA_character_`  .  If that doesn't help, please consider to ask a new question with a reproducible example and expected output.

Comment: Related question, regarding characters in the data table and a warning using this function, asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711685/sample-a-single-row-per-column-with-substantial-missing-data

Answer (score 0):

To ignore `NA`s just pass one more argument to the summarize function `na.rm = TRUE`. it will ignore all the `NA`s.

I used `dplyr` to perform the requested grouping but you can use base function also. `dplyr` is easy to use and read.

below is the code

if the summarise function is same for all columns you can use `summarise_each` and do the grouping in one go.

```
library(dplyr)

    df = df %>%
      group_by(Group) %>%
      summarise(Var_1 = max(Var_1, na.rm = TRUE),Var_2 = max(Var_2, na.rm = TRUE),Var_3 = min(Var_3, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Your code computes the max and min of variables instead of a randomly picked value and it will be impractical for op's real data with 50k+ variables.

Comment: I have just used max/min, just for illustration. One can use any other aggregating function (even custom functions) which suits their needs. If OP needs to pick a random number. He/She can use Sample function to pick a random number.